# Conditionally fill in a vector using the index of TRUE values in two other vectors

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, vector

I have two vectors of TRUE/FALSE values:

```
x1 <- c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
  FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
  TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)

x2 <- c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)
```

I want to take the indexes of TRUE values in `x1` and `x2` and fill the new vector with `0.75` and `-0.25` in those indexes respectively. All other cells will be `0`.

```
which(x1)
[1]  1  3  5 19

which(x2)    
[1]  2  4  6 20
```

Therefore, the final vector will have `0.75` in indexes 1, 3, 5, 19 and `-0.25` in indexes 2, 4, 6, 20.

How can I achieve this in R?

**SOLUTION:**

I found the way to do it.

```
newx <- rep(0, length(x1))
newx [which(x1)] <- 0.75
newx [which(x2)] <- -0.25
```

Comment: `c(0, .75, -.25)[x1 + x2 * 2 + 1]`

Comment: @DavidArenburg This is a nice solution. The OP changed the desired output a couple of times and therefore the provided solutions might not be up to date.

Answer (score 1):

If `x1` is equal to `TRUE` we assign `.75`. For cases where `x1` is not `TRUE`, we look if `x2` is `TRUE` and assign the value `-.25`. In case both `x1` and `x2` equal `FALSE`, assign the value `0`.

```
ifelse(x1, 0.75, ifelse(x2, -.25, 0))
#[1]  0.75 -0.25  0.75 -0.25  0.75 -0.25  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.75 -0.25  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
```

Comment: Although your code snippet might solve the issue, you should describe what’s the purpose of your code (how it solves the problem). Furthermore, you might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Two notes: 1) `isTRUE(x1)` is better than the comparison you are using; 2) if `x1` is equal to `TRUE` then you don't need the comparison at all, `ifelse(x1, 0.75, etc)` will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
x1_number <- ifelse(x1 == TRUE, yes = 0.75, no = 0)
x2_number <- ifelse(x2 == TRUE, yes = -1, no = 0)

df <- data.frame(your_column_name = x1_number + x2_number)
```